# PHP custom static method access

Tags: php, static-methods

I'm in PHP and I must access a Static method of an object which name must change.

```
   private $controlleur = null;
   private static $instance = null;

   private function __construct() {
     $nomControlleur = "Controlleurs\_" . Session::singleton()->controlleur;
     $this->controlleur = $nomControlleur::singleton();
   }
```

This preceding code is giving me " Syntax error unexpected :: ". 
I've also tried writing {$nomControlleur}::singleton(); but it's giving me even more errors,
thanks a lot for your help.

Balls of steel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
$this->controlleur = call_user_func(array($nomControlleur, 'singleton'));
```

or (5.2.3+ only)

```
$this->controlleur = call_user_func($nomControlleur . '::singleton');
```

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
$staticCall = $nonController."::singleton()";
$staticCall();
```

?

Comment: Thanks, nearly that, but I have find it with your comment. Just pull of the () in singleton() beacause when you call it it gives singleton()();

Answer (score 0):

I think now in PHP 5.3 there is also PHP `__callStatic()` as there was `__call()`.

So you can define `__callStatic()` and undefined static method call will hit this method.

Please check here for more details and usage.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.callstatic